# loops and functions questions

Tags: function, loops

Why am I getting an error instead of expected output

```js
let marks = {
  harry: 44,
  shg: 544,
  ccc: 44,
  gugugu: 99
}
for (let i = 0; i < object.keys(marks).length; i++) {
  console.log("marks of " + object.keys(marks)[i] + "are" + marks[object.keys(marks)[i]])
}
```

```
ReferenceError: object is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/practice-set-on-loopsandfunctions-course-12/index.js:7:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:14)
```

Expected output

```
marks of  harry are  44
marks of  shg  are 544
marks of ccc are  44
marks of gugugu are 99
```

Comment: I don't see any "questions" here.

Answer (score 0):

Use capital `Object`

```js
let marks = {
  harry: 44,
  shg: 544,
  ccc: 44,
  gugugu: 99
}
for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(marks).length; i++) {
  console.log("marks of " + Object.keys(marks)[i] + "are" + marks[Object.keys(marks)[i]])
}
```

There are cleaner loops if you'd like `for(let key in marks)` then you don't have to transform keys to a list each time

```js
let marks = {
  harry: 44,
  shg: 544,
  ccc: 44,
  gugugu: 99
}
for (let key in marks) {
  console.log("marks of " + key + "are" + marks[key])
}
```